# QGIS: CRS and CRS in extent different - what to do?

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile from a gpkg which has a CRS of EPSG:3035 ETRS89-Extended / LAEA Europe -Projected. If I change this to EPSG 25832 (by exporting the layer, saving the features with the CRS EPSG 25832), the new shapefile has the proper CRS, but the extent is still in the old projection (see image). In general, the file lines up properly, but I get an error when I try to select features with the tool 'select by location' (when I create a buffer from it to select features from another layer). I get the error, that the projection is wrong. So what can, or need, I to do?

EDIT: I tried this the other way around, and it is the same: the extent is not changing, but it stays in its old extent.

Further, when I reproject with pyqgis, the extent is correctly set to the new CRS. So I guess it must have something to do with the reprojecting function behind the export of features? Does this use another function than when you call the pyqgis function 'qgis:reprojectLayer'? I'm not really asking a question here, just trying to find out what causes the not-updating of the extents when you export and save features in a new coordinate system.

QGIS 3.28 Firenze
Windows 10

[image]